# Multiple login tests on mobile app with UFT

Tags: testing, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to test the Login feature of my Android app with multiple user-password entries that I have in an Excel. I have already been able to import that data from the Excel successfully and run the same test with each row (with "Run on all Rows" option), but now I am facing a problem that I am not being able to solve.

After a test runs with one row, one the test starts over with a new row, it will not restart the app, but start at the same point where the previous one finished. I think this is not the expected behaviour, in general, since most of the GUI testing tools restart the app when testing a feature with parametrization (data from Excel, mostly). Anyway, I "fixed" this by logging out in my app.

In this case there was an "easy solution" by logging out. But what if I was testing a different feature in which I cannot simply "log out". The problem is that in those different cases I would have to navigate back or do something that may fail and has nothing to do with the feature I am testing.

I am not sure if I am not using the right approach. Is there a good general solution for this issue?

Comment: What exactly you have set up to `Run on all Rows`?

Comment: The test. I did it on the test settings (right click on the test > *Settings* > *Run* > *Data Table iterations*: *Run on all Rows*).

Comment: Which `test` you are talking about? Do you mean `Action`?

Comment: In the "navigator" of UFT there is a *Solution*, below that, there is my *test* and below it, there is an Action (with the code). The option about running on all rows is selected in the settings of the test. Anyway, this part of the test is working.

Comment: Have you tried by making the same selection in `Action Properties`? `(Right click on action -> Action Properties)`

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing in `Action Properties` :(

Comment: First get the `Test Flow` view, then `Right click on action -> Action Properties`.  Check [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g2MY5.jpg) image.

Comment: Found it, but still not working as expected. I tried both with Test's "Run on all Rows" and Action's "Run on all Rows" enabled, and only Action's. In the first case I get the same result so far and in the second it just runs the action in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following two ways to solve your problem if you cannot simply use logout as the last step.

1. **Use App.Launch function**  you can add one line to the top of your script like **Device("iPhone 7").App("myApp").Launch NotInstall, Restart** . Here the device and the app can be TO in object repository or identified using descriptive programing like Device("id:=123456")
2. **Check options in Test Settings**  Please check the latest UFT version maybe 12.53 or later if there are any options in Test Settings for users to choose to restart or reinstall app for iterations.

Thanks